# In Flutter on Android: how to save non-image file so the user can instantly see it in other apps?

Tags: android, flutter, file, android-file, storage-access-framework

How can I save a file (txt/pdf/doc etc.) in my Flutter app on Android device in such a way that it will be accessible or "visible to the user" from any other app like an email client?

The desired behavior is very simple:

1. My app saves a file - in its own folder provided by path_provider or any other place.
2. User opens any other app that can read files on device, say an email client.
3. User can instantly see the file that my app previously saved when open the typical 'Attach file' dialog or w/e.

Sounds pretty basic, but so far I could not achieve this result. I save files just fine and I tried different folders (hello path_provider), but it seems that it doesn't matter where my app saves the files - they just don't show up in other apps. Files are not images, just documents.
Beyond that, the files that my app saves this way are obviously accessible via browsing through the standard "Files" app on device and via other means like connecting to a PC.

Is there a way to "flag" them for the system to show? I don't see any documentation mentioning this problem.

Comment: On Android 11+ devices an app can only see its own files and some common mediafiles. If it wants to see all files it should go for permission MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE or use Storage Access Framework to let the user select files or folders.

Comment: The Files app will have permission MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. Your mail app -which one?- not. Or not use SAF.

Comment: Further: if you create a file you should add code to let it be indexed by media store as many apps use media store to browse for files.

Comment: @blackapps Excatly - I need to add it somehow. Any ideas? My app saves, let's say, a PDF file. I want any other app like Gmail to be able to see it in 'Recent' or at least 'Downloads' when user presses "Attach a file" there. What is the correct and legit way to actually do this now? I don't want my app to 'get all the permissions' just because of this particular need.. tbh, READ/WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE should be enough for such things or it's just bad system design.

Comment: I told what you have to do already. And as i dont program in Flutter i cannot tell you how exactly. But as you are not the only one using Flutter and that what you want is pretty basic you should be able to find the right code with simple search.

Comment: @blackapps yeah well, I wouldn't ask here if it was so obvious from inside Flutter^^ I mean, it's obvious that I need to "flag" them or in your words - have files indexed by the system - I worte it in my question. Problem is, Flutter is too "high level" for this - to do this kind of system manipulations it relies heavily on plugins that are mostly written in Java. I kinda hoped to avoid writing another one, but oh well. As a side note I had no problems adding images from my app to be visible in system gallery, other files - no luck. Will keep on trying..

Comment: One way of doing this, as I see it via SAF - is creating a custom document provider for the app, though I've no idea how to mate (not a typo) it with Flutter.

Comment: Using MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is not a valid solution, because Google play team will ask you the reason to use such permission and it needs to be a CORE feature! Like a file explore app o an antivirus app. Save a file is not a valid reason and it will be rejected...